# How can I see the design view in Visual Studio 2012 for ASP.NET projects?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing a website using ASP.NET.

When I start writing code, I do not get a design view to design the website (please see screenshot in the link below). I really need help.

http://www.4shared.com/download/CZTzYSUu/18-09-34_06-13-06_.png?tsid=20130726-032036-c925f200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to View and click Designer in Visual Studio . I think you should reinstall Visual Studio 2012 because as I can see from your screenshot, not only you dont  have the designer file, but  also you don't have the code file. So a reinstall is a better option for you.

Answer (score 9):

Tools > Options > HTML designer > Enable HTML designer

Comment: For some reason that check must have disappeared.  Thanks for helping!